# Visual Studio Pre-build action to embed external xml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm on visual studio 2019 and developing a VSTO application using C#. I'm using WPF and MVVM by use of VSTOContrib library. The library uses naming convention to couple view (xml file) and viewmodel at runtime by searching the assembly.

**The problem:**

The view (xml file) is managed externally by non-developers in a separate folder. And this folder's path is unchangeable.

I've come to the conclusion the best course of action would be to embed the file at build time using pre-build actions however after hours of research I've been unable to find any information on the subject.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an itemgroup to your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="path/to/the/file.xml" LogicalName="Name.Of.The.Resource" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It can be an absolute or a relative path. The compiler will take care of the process of embedding the file for you. Optionally add the `LogicalName` attribute to set the name of the embedded resource. It not specified, msbuild will use the filename to generate a name for you.